# Form POST gives empty model fields when using EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I have a form which I am wanting to place in multiple views. Currently when I submit this form, the model return has null for all it's values and i am unsure why.

When I debug through it is reaching the POST event but the model values are null. (not the model itself).

Contact Model

```
public class ContactModel : BasePageModel
{
    public string Introduction { get; set; }
    public ContactForm Form { get; set; }
    public ContactModel(TreeNode node, ContactForm form = null) : base(node)
    {
        Introduction = node.GetEditableTextStringValue("Introduction", String.Empty);
        Form = form;
    }
}
```

View Model for the form

```
public class ContactForm
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SendContact(ContactForm model)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

This is the view of the page I want to "embed" if you will the contact form I want to submit.

```
@model MVCApp.Models.PageModels.ContactModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendContact", "Contact", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Form)
}
```

And the editor template of the Contact Form itself

```
@model MVCApp.Models.FormModels.ContactForm
....
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "")

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "")

....
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The form renders both parts (The surrounding text and fields) as well as the contact form correctly. But as I said above when I click on submit the model that gets passed back in the POST to the controller (which it does hit through debugging) has all it's fields as null.

Any pointers in where I may have gone wrong would be great.

Comment: Because the model in the view is `ContactModel` so your POST method needs to be `public ActionResult SendContact(ContactModel model)` (not `ContactForm`) - or you can use `[Bind(Prefix = "Form ")]ContactForm model)`

Comment: And you need to add a parameter-less constructor to your `ContactModel` otherwise and exception will be thrown when you submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking this as the answer since Stephens comment can't be marked as such.

Using Stephens suggestion, I changed the ActionResult to use

```
        public ActionResult SendContact([Bind(Prefix = "Form")]ContactForm model)
```

And it worked perfectly. The fields and the model are populated correctly.